# System not loading after trying to run in safe mode

Tags: macos

I am using Yosemite I tried to upgrade its version and I started seeing busy cursor. I then tried to run in safe mode and since then not booting up.  Verify and repair disk failing too. For safe mode I press shift key in start. What do I do now? Right now I don't have startup disk either

[image]

Ran in single mode and I get this
[image]

Forced fschk now gives this error

I had run command *fsck_hfs -y -Rc -d /dev/disk0s2* which also changed volume to *Recovery mode* and now n boot always show recovery screen. Is my data safe?

Smart status verified

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I/O error" would indicate the drive is failing, physically. Simplest would be to swap drives & restore from Time Machine. If no backup, then stop trying to 'fix' the drive & instead turn to data recovery options.

Comment: It's failing for Macintosh HD volume and for base file system it verified OK. How all of sudden a new drive stopped failing after running to safe mode?

Comment: @Tetsujin check updated question

Comment: I doubt the problem has anything to do with safe mode -- from your description, I'd guess the disk was already having trouble during the upgrade (causing the busy cursor), and that trying to install the upgrade files on a bad disk corrupted the volume.

Comment: @GordonDavisson you seem right. Now issue is I ran forced fschk and now it turned volume to *recovery HD* and locked. Is my data safe?

Comment: I q run *fschk-hfs -r ..* it rebuilt catalog and now changed volume t recovery HD

Comment: I am going to echo the "your disk is failing" sentiment already here.  To verify this, boot into recovery or off an Installer and launch Terminal and execute this command:  `diskutil info /dev/disk0 | grep -i smart`   If it returns anything but "Verified", your disk is dying and it's time for a new one.

Comment: Your data is *not* safe; depending on the extent of the failure, it *might* be recoverable. I'd recommend against further attempts to repair the volume, since if the drive has a hardware problem it's just likely to make things worse. I'd replace the drive, install a new OS, *then* try to recover any important files from the old drive. Actually, I'd recommend taking it to a repair shop (and make sure they either can do data recovery themselves, or at least will give you the old drive back so you can take it somewhere else).

Comment: @GordonDavisson while I can't see my data files after running forced fschk, will my data be visible if I use it as external drive and access in Windows?

Comment: No, Windows doesn't know how to read the volume format OS X uses (Mac OS Extended) without additional software (and with the right additional software, it'd see a corrupt volume and refuse to mount it). If you want to try recovering the files yourself, the first thing I'd try is installing [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) on another Mac (or your Mac with a new internal system disk), connecting the damaged drive as an external, then using DiskWarrior's capability to mount a virtual cleaned-up version (*not* to try to repair the disk), and copy files from that.

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that the DiskWarrior approach will work; t depends on exactly what's gone wrong and how bad the damage is. In my experience, data recovery often involves trying a bunch of different things to see what'll work (and if how they fail gives an indication of what else to try). There's no single procedure that "just works".

Comment: @GordonDavisson why thvolume changed from *Macintosh HD* to *Recovery HD* also did I do blunder to keep data files in Mac. Partition and I should have created non Mac partition, if possible, for data files?

Comment: And it also says volume is locked

Comment: @Allan smart status verified question updated

Comment: @GordonDavisson question updated with image . Smart status. Is verified

Comment: Unfortunately, SMART status being "Verified" does not mean much. Recovery HD is a different (normally hidden) partition used for recovery mode. Mac format is not a mistake, it just means you need Mac recovery tools, not Windows recovery tools. Your real mistake is not having a backup.